# How to include QtQuickControls

Tags: qt, qml, scrollview, scrollbar, qtquickcontrols

I've included to my project :

`"import QtQuickQontrols 1.4"`

But now I need to use ScrollBar , and for this, I need to include

`"import QtQuickControls 2.2"`

But when I include version 2.2 and delete 1.4,  my project is ruined... MenuBar, TableView is under errors! Ok, when I include both this version it's errors , too!
I did run qmake, and give me some advice what should I do to implement my ScrollBar.
I've tried to add ScrollView, but inside this it doesn't work :

```
     ....
      ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {...} ...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to import both controls 1 & 2, they will have name collisions. But you can rename them so they don't conflict:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QC1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2 as QC2

QC1.MenuBar {
}

QC2.ScrollBar {
}
```